# I'm building poky for i.mx8m in a docker container and facing problem where do_image_ostreecommit fails to get acquire lock with permission denied

Tags: docker, yocto, imx8

```
ERROR: hotpot-qt6-image-1.0-r0 do_image_ostreecommit: Unable to acquire lock 'Permission denied', /opt/yocto/ostree_repo/ostree.lock
ERROR: hotpot-qt6-image-1.0-r0 do_image_ostreecommit: SystemExit(1)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/builduser/build/tmp/work/imx8mp_leica_sx8p-poky-linux/hotpot-qt6-image/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_image_ostreecommit.48705
ERROR: Task (/home/builduser/hotpot-core/meta-leica-middleware/recipes-core/images/hotpot-qt6-image.bb:do_image_ostreecommit) failed with exit code '1'
```

I try giving `chmod 777 -R /opt/yocto/ostree_repo` folder in docker build yet not eorking.

Comment: I was using command to run docker as `-coker run -v /home/user/ostree_repo:/opt/yocto/ostree_repo` to mount a host folder in container. The host folder was not created into host, still poky build command running in docker is creating the folder but not able to create lock files in it. And that's why giving error as permission denied to acquire lock.
After deleting and creating the folder at `/home/user/ostree_dir` in host, problem is solved and it works fine.